# Is my wine safe to drink?

Tags: airlock, safety

I began making a few gallons of mango wine a few months back, and it was fermenting very well.  I got all of the fruit and debris out a week or so after I started it, but I kept it fermenting in the primary fermenter. As things turned out, before it was finished with the primary fermentation, I decided to take a break from drinking for a while, and I ended up neglecting it for a long while. When I finally got around to checking on it some 6 months or so later, the air lock had dried out. I went to go pour it out, but when I opened the lid, the wine was clear, smelled of alcohol and mango, and I think it might be good still, even though the airlock was probably gone for a long time. I'm wondering, is it still safe to drink?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer **Yes**

No known harmful pathogens can survive in beer or wine.

From your disciption there seems to be no sign of acetobacter which can sour the wine, usually it will have a pellicle on top. But even then is safe to drink.

Let us know how it is, sounds like a nice wine.

Comment: "No pathogens can survive in beer or wine" - this is really dangerous oversimplification. Up to 70% alcohol some pathogens may survive. Below 40% not all even form spores. So while I agree his wine is probably safe, your answer may cause harmful mislead.

Comment: @Mołot thank you.  Edited to reflect how John Palmer stated it in How to Brew.

Comment: @Mołot alcohol alone isn't the only featurer of beer and wine, that keeps it safe. The low pH plays a big role. What people offten forget is that this stuff has been made for 1000's of years with far less sanitary conditions. Fermentaion is what allowed humans to safe drink when water sources would litterally kill you. And make old rotten fruit and vegetables useable, or even directly eatable.

Comment: I didn't forget any of that. I also didn't forget the training we gave to bacteria in the last 70 or so years. Antibiotics, plant protection chemicals etc have a long term effect of making them much more survivable. Today's salmonella probably can survive in beer, if I remember paper correctly. Some others, too. Not so long ago they couldn't...

Comment: @Mołot well when you find that paper, or find a documented case of illness cause by a beer or wine pathogen. Let us know because every how to brew book needs a revision. I noted my refference, you should do the same before spewing misinformation. Even the president of the AHA has gone on record with the statement I paraphrased.

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22004814 "they could survive for more than 30 days in the mid-strength beer when held at 4°C" - so, pretty much all lagers, isn't it? Check before calling something misinformation, please.

Comment: @Mołot you may want to read the abstract again, or buy the article.  I think you will find it interesting how they define Mid strength beer, and that this was ideal lab conditions, and they were only able to get them to "survive" in a state that were the pathogen was not able to reproduce. And it says nothing of the pathogens viability after being in the beer only that is was technically alive for a short time.

Comment: All I was saying is that your sentence is false. And, as stated, it is. known harmful pathogens *can* survive in beer, and it was proven. And you claim they can't - at least you oversimplified. End of story, good night.

Comment: @Mołot no, all you showed was a study were they were able to get 2 pathogens to survive a short time under lab conditions in an ethanol solution with simular pH and abv to beer.

Comment: So you're both right.  Thanks for the exchange, I learned something, no kidding...cheers.  *drinks beer perhaps with harmful pathogens that aren't known to be harmful to injest*

Comment: I tasted it, and to my surprise, it was very good. I racked it into three gallon sized bottles and affixed proper air locks.

Comment: @ChadLong good deal. Going to age it longer then?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably ok, but try a sip first before guzzling it. How does it taste? Does it have enough alcohol to preserve it? The magic number for that is 12.3% ABV.

Airlocks don't guarantee freedom from contamination and nor does lack of fluid in an airlock guarantee contamination. The water just helps. The bend in the pipe is really enough to stop most contaminants, and the water will remove some more but not necessarily all.